# float variable doesn't meet the conditions (C)

Tags: c, variables, floating-point, while-loop

I'm trying to get the user to input a number between 1.00000 to 0.00001 while edges not included into a float variable. I can assume that the user isn't typing more than 5 numbers after the dot.
now, here is what I have written:

```
printf("Enter required Leibniz gap.(Between 0.00001 to 1.00000)\n");
scanf("%f", &gap);
while ((gap < 0.00002) || (gap > 0.99999))
{
printf("Enter required Leibniz gap.(Between 0.00001 to 1.00000)\n");
scanf("%f", &gap);
}
```

now, when I'm typing the smallest number possible: 0.00002 in getting stuck in the while loop.
when I run the debugger I saw that 0.00002 is stored with this value in the float variable: 1.99999995e-005 
anybody can clarify for me what am I doing wrong? why isn't 0.00002 meeting the conditions? what is this "1.99999995e-005" thing.

Comment: What's the type of `gap`?

Comment: your conditions don't match your user instructions! 0.00001 < 0.00002

Comment: The range in the prompt is inconsistent with the numbers you're checking against. `0.00002` is not the immediate successor of `0.00001`; there are plenty of values between them. Once you fix that, you'll find that the value `0.00001` cannot be represented exactly in binary floating-point.

Comment: I am allowed to assume that the user won't type more than 5 numbers after the dot.

Comment: Why not `gap <= 0.00001 || gap >= 1.0`?

Comment: `1.99999995e-005` means `1.99999995 * 10^(-5)`. This is how floating point numbers are represented in computer: exponent (number from 1 to 2) and mantissa (power of 10). Because of that, you can not represent certain numbers accurately in binary format, so you have some data loss, and in your case the "rounded" number does not fit your conditions

Comment: possible duplicate of [Floating point numbers do not work as expected](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7350558/floating-point-numbers-do-not-work-as-expected)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`float`s are not capable of storing exact values for every possible number (infinite numbers between 0-1 therefore impossible). Assigning 0.00002 to a float will have a different but really close number due to the implementation which is what you are experiencing. Precision decreases as the number grows.

So you can't directly compare two close floats and have healthy results.

More information on floating points can be found [on this Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point).

What you could do is emulate fixed point math. Have an `int n = 100000;` to represent `1.00000`  internally (1000 -> 0.001 and such) and do calculations accordingly or use a fixed point math library.

Comment: `floats` are exact values.  It the operation that is inexact.  Going from a string like "0.00002" to a `float` often ends up in an inexact _conversion_, not an inexact `float` result.

Answer (score 3):

The problem here is that you are using a `float` variable (`gap`), but you are comparing it with a `double` constant (`0.00002`). The constant is `double` because floating-point constants in C are double unless otherwise specified.

An underlying issue is that the number `0.00002` is not representable in either `float` or `double`. (It's not representable at all in binary floating point because it's binary expansion is infinitely long, like the decimal expansion of ⅓.) So when you write `0.00002` in a program, the C compiler substitutes it with a `double` value which is very close to `0.00002`. Similarly, when `scanf` reads the number `0.00002` into a `float` variable, it substitutes a `float` value which is very close to `0.00002`. Since `double` numbers have more bits than `floats`, the `double` value is closer to `0.00002` than the `float` value.

When you compare two floating point values with different precision, the compiler converts the value with less precision into exactly the same value with more precision. (The set of values representable as `double` is a superset of the set of values representable as `float`, so it is always possible to find a `double` whose value is the same as the value of a `float`.) And that's what happens when `gap < 0.00002` is executed: `gap` is converted to the `double` of the same value, and that is compared with the double (close to) `0.00002`. Since both of these values are actually slightly less than 0.00002, and the `double` is closer, the `float` is less than the `double`.

You can solve this problem in a couple of ways. First, you can avoid the conversion, either by making `gap` a `double` and changing the `scanf` format to `%lf`, or by comparing `gap` to a `float`:

```
while (gap < 0.00002F || gap > 0.99999F) {
```

But that's not really correct, for a couple of reasons. First, there is actually no guarantee that the floating point conversion done by the C compiler is the same as the conversion done by the standard library (`scanf`), and the standard allows the compiler to use "either the nearest representable value, or the larger or smaller representable value immediately adjacent to the nearest representable value, chosen in an implementation-defined manner." (It doesn't specify in detail which value `scanf` produces either, but recommends that it be the nearest representable value.) As it happens, `gcc` and `glibc` (the C compiler and standard library used on Linux) both produce the nearest representable value, but other implementations don't.

Anyway, according to your error message, you want the value to be between `0.00001` and `1.00000`. So your test should be precisely that:

```
while (gap <= 0.00001F || gap >= 1.0000F) { ...
```

(assuming you keep `gap` as a `float`.)

Any of the above solutions will work. Personally, I'd make `gap` a `double` in order to make the comparison more intuitive, and also change the comparison to compare against `0.00001` and `1.0000`.

By the way, the `E-05` suffix means "times ten to the power of -5" (the `E` stands for `Exponent`). You'll see that a lot; it's a standard way of writing floating point constants.

Answer (score 2):

Fraction part of single precision floating numbers can represent numbers from -2 to 2-2^-23 and have a fraction part with smallest quantization step of 2^-23. So if some value cannot be represented with a such step then it represented with a nearest value according to [IEEE 754 rounding rules](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754-2008#Rounding_rules):

```
0.00002*32768 = 0.655360043     // floating point exponent is chosen.
0.655360043/(2^-23) = 5497558.5 // is not an integer multiplier 
                                // of quantization step, so the 
5497558*(2^-23) = 0.655359983   // nearest value is chosen
5497559*(2^-23) = 0.655360103   // from these two variants
```

First one variant equals to 1.999969797×10⁻⁵ in decimal format and the second one equals to 1.999999948×10⁻⁵ (just to compare - if we choose 5497560 we get 2.000000677×10⁻⁵). So the second variant can be choosen as a result and its value is not equal to 0.00002.

The total precision of floating point number depends on exponent value as well (takes values from -128 to 127): it can be computed by multiplication of fraction part quantization step and exponent value. In case of 0.00002 total precision is (2^-23)×(2^-15) = 3.6×(10^-12). It means if we add to 0.00002 a value which is smaller than a half of this value than 0.00002 remains the same. In general it means that numbers of floating point number which is meaningful are from 1×exponent to 2×(10^-23)×exponent. 

That is why a very popular approach is to compare two floating numbers using some epsilon value which is greater than quantization step.

Comment: `FLT_EPSILON` value is quantization step from 1.0f.  The quantization step from 2.0f up is `FLT_EPSILON*2.0f`, etc.

Comment: @chux Thanks for comment. Added more details to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Like some of the comments said, due to how floating point numbers are represented, you will see errors like this. 
A solution to this is convert it to

```
gap + 1e-8 < 0.0002
```

This gives you a small window of tolerance enough to let most cases you want to pass and most you dont want to fail